# How to find the vector equation of the line through a point, contained in a plane and incident a line

Tags: geometry

I have to find the vectorial equation of the line through $A=(1,1,4)$, contained in the plane $\pi_A:x+y−z+2=0$ and incident  the line $r:(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)+\lambda(1,1,-1)$! thank you very much!

Comment: what about showing some self effort this time?

Comment: yes, I know you may think I didn't try anything... but actually I don't know to move... tomorrow I have an exam on this stuff... :'(

Comment: Yeah, I know....but what did **you try** at all? You must know *at least* definitions, ways to form planes and stuff, or else your expectatives for tomorrow's test should be rather low. Show some *intent* at least, so that people won't feel like doing your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really sorry, this is my last question! heeelpp meee!!

Comment: I tried with systems, I tried matrix... but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Since its a homework, I will provide hints.

HINTS:

1. Find the point of intersection of plane $\pi_A$ and line $r$.
2. Your answer is the equation of the line passing through the above point and $A$.